# Creating and updating Model object using form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

models.py

```js
class PostModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.TextField(null=True)
    body = models.TextField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class ImagesPostModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(PostModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```js
def post(request):
    post = PostModel(user=request.user)
    post.save()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostModelForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        images = request.FILES.getlist('images')
        for image in images:
            ImagesPostModel.objects.create(post=post, images=image)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/Blog/home/')
    else:
        form = PostModelForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'post.html', {'form': form})
```

I created a PostModel object post and save it in the database using save() method. I have provided the instance parameter as post object in the form, so the form should be updating the above created post but it is creating another PostModel object and inserting into the database by itself. So there are two post begin created and being inserted into the database, first one is because of post = PostModel(user=request.user) and I dont know why the second one is being created.
why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first 2 lines in the view

```
post = PostModel(user=request.user)
post.save()
```

As they create a PostModel obj with user=currentuser

To add the post to the user do the following rather than `form.save()`

```
post = form.save(commit=False)
post.user = request.user
post.save()
```

Comment: A user can have any number of posts. What should I do then?

Comment: Check Updated answer

Comment: Please accept the answer to close the question.